# Simple PHP lock file function

Tags: php, scripting, cookies, symlink

Could anyone please help with a PHP lock file function ?

I want to create a symlink when a URL like this is followed (with the filename being the characters after "file="):

`http://www.blah.com/download.php?file=zFZpj4b2AkEFz%2B3O`

and then I need to deny access if the symlink exists ... but I'm out of my dept !

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example (comments are mine) taken from the [PHP Manual for `is_link()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php):

```
<?php
$link = 'uploads';

if (is_link($link)) { // check if the link exists
    echo(readlink($link)); // echo out path this link points to
    // this is where you ban access
} else {
    symlink('uploads.php', $link); // create the symlink
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a shell script with chmod to restrict access. Use exec function in php.

```
ln -s mysymlink
if [  -f mysymlink ] then
    chmod 000 filenametobedenied
fi
```

this could be the shell script  save it in the document root as filecheck.sh and run this script throgh the exec('filecheck.sh') function

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that I follow, could you elaborate please ?

Comment: Create a shell script with shell command for creating symbolic link,search for a particular file and then change permission for the desired file.

Comment: then run that shell script through exec function in php

Comment: `code` ln -s mysymlink
if [  -f mysymlink ] then
 chmod 000 filenametobedenied
fi `code`  this could be the shell script  save it in the document root as filecheck.sh and run this script throgh the exec('filecheck.sh') function

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s mysymlink
if [  -f mysymlink ] then
    chmod 000 filenametobedenied
fi
```

this could be the shell script  save it in the document root as filecheck.sh and run this script throgh the exec('filecheck.sh') function

Comment: Edit your original answer with this.

Comment: Thank you Treffynnon .I tried to edit the comment before and failed, thats why I posted again.Now i only i noticed the edit button under the answer.